# Is this function considered a side effect, thus bad FP design?

Tags: scala, http, functional-programming

```
  private def retrieveSongId(songName: String): Option[JsValue] = {
    val geniusStringResponse = Http("https://api.genius.com/search?q=" + formattedSongName)
      .param("access_token", apiKey)
      .asString
      .body

    //Extra processing with geniusStringResponse   
    }
  }
```

Will the above function be considered a side effect due to the HTTP request? If so, is Scala code like this appropriate?

Comment: I don't see this method "changing" its "environment" in any way in the given line. So, it does not look like a side-effect.

Comment: Performing a HTTP request is definitely a side effect. But whether or not this is bad design will depend on who you ask...

Comment: Side effects are not bad. Uncontrolled side-effects intermingled with logic is bad. I don't think it's possible to have a program with no side-effects if you include "heating the room" as a side-effect.

Comment: It’s definitely a side effect because the remote can return a different result for that query. Maybe not immediate subsequent requests, but the search results could be different as time goes on. A good way to question the purity of the function is whether you could write a unit test against it; can you guarantee that Google will return the same 10 results for `“?q=functional+programming”` every time you run it? It’s necessarily a side effect but not necessarily bad design. If your program is to fetch remote data, what other choice do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, calling this function has the side effect of making an HTTP request. Calling this function may affect the result of another function (e.g. `getSearchCount`), and this function may return different results given the same input values (e.g. the server is not available all the time).

However this does not mean it is not appropriate. Any usable Scala program is going to have side effects, but the trick is to keep them as constrained as possible. A well-written Scala program will have a rich set of side-effect free classes and functions, and a relatively light layer of non-functional code that calls them.

In this case, for example, you should have a simple function that does the HTTP request and a second function that processes the results. The result-processing function can be pure functional code, and can be effectively tested with mock data.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. Doing some more research I see a monad is commonly used for IO operations as a solution for this. Is it acceptable to do use a monad for my purposes above (and also other IO operations such as Database)?